# Python Terminal Keep closing, was working earlier

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I coded this snippet below in python was working great I restarted my PC and now it instant closes the window no matter what I put! I would really need some help!

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Jimmy\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')

elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('mustard')

k=input("press close to exit")
```

It says `File "C:/Users/Jimmy/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/test.py", line 3
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Jimmy\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Comment: Take `'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/pants'` out maybe? And replace it with the path of Chromedriver?

Comment: Oops now it says 

Read above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"<your path>\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Just about to post this :)

Comment: Wait for the hollow checkmark after around 10 mins, and then click it.